# How to sort a dictionary in Python with keys of mixed letters and numbers?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict_str = {'Number_1_item':'foo',
            'Number_11_item':'bar',
            'Number_22_item':'foobar',
            'Number_5_item':'barfoo'}
```

And my desired out put is:

```
sorted_dict_str = {'Number_1_item':'foo',
            'Number_5_item':'bar',
            'Number_11_item':'foobar',
            'Number_22_item':'barfoo'}
```

So the sorted_dict_str is sorted in numerical way based on the keys in dict_str.
I have found some answers to sort the keys with pure numeric keys but not mixed ones, so they are not really helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Regards

Comment: FWIW, a plain `dict` in Python is an unordered collection. There is `OrderedDict` in the `collections` module which retains insertion order (by using an internal list to remember insertion order), and in CPython 3.6+ a plain `dict` remembers insertion order, but that's currently an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: You will need to create a key function that parses the numeric component from the key and converts it to `int`. If your keys are like that shown in your question you can use 2 string slicing operations to do the parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get sorted dict from your dict like that:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

OrderedDict(sorted(dict_str.items(), key=lambda s: int(s[0].split('_')[1])))
```

Answer (score 2):

If we can assume that all the keys are on the format `Number_XX_item`, you could simply sort on the numeric part, using a lambda:

```
sorted_dict_str = sorted(dict_str.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('_')[1]))
```

This gives the following output:

```
sorted_dict_str = 
[('Number_1_item', 'foo'), 
 ('Number_5_item', 'barfoo'), 
 ('Number_11_item', 'bar'), 
 ('Number_22_item', 'foobar')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution. When executing the sorted function it'll return a sorted list of all the keys in the dictionary. A dictionary can't be sorted (though there is a way of having an [ordered dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)).

This Solution is also more robust compared to the first solution, since the number can be anywhere in the key.

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict 

d = {'Number_1_item':'foo',
            'Number_11_item':'bar',
            'Number_22_item':'foobar',
            'Number_5_item':'barfoo'}

keys = d.keys()

def sort_mixed(key):
    int_match = re.search(r'(?P<int>\d+)', key)
    number = int_match.group(0)
    return int(number)

sorted_keys = sorted(keys, key=lambda key: sort_mixed(key))
print(sorted_keys) # print sorted keys

sorted_dict = OrderedDict((k, d[k]) for k in sorted_keys)
print(sorted_dict)  # print new sorted dict
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort). There are ways to do it by yourself, without importing extra modules, but I like is method.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> import natsort

>>> input_dict = {'Number_1_item':'foo', 'Number_11_item':'bar', 'Number_22_item':'foobar', 'Number_5_item':'barfoo'}

>>> OrderedDict(natsort.natsorted(input_dict.items()))

OrderedDict([('Number_1_item', 'foo'), ('Number_5_item', 'barfoo'), ('Number_11_item', 'bar'), ('Number_22_item', 'foobar')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the slicing technique I mentioned in the comments. This is less robust than using `.split`, since the lengths of the prefix & suffix strings are hard-coded, but it's slightly faster because slicing is fast compared to a method call.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

dict_str = {
    'Number_1_item':'foo',
    'Number_11_item':'bar',
    'Number_22_item':'foobar',
    'Number_5_item':'barfoo',
}

skeys = sorted(dict_str.keys(), key=lambda s: int(s[7:][:-5]))
sorted_dict = OrderedDict((k, dict_str[k]) for k in skeys)
pprint(sorted_dict)
```

**output**

```
OrderedDict([('Number_1_item', 'foo'),
             ('Number_5_item', 'barfoo'),
             ('Number_11_item', 'bar'),
             ('Number_22_item', 'foobar')])
```

---

You could also do the sorting on the (key, value) pairs inside the `OrderedDict` constructor call:

```
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(dict_str.items(), key=lambda u: int(u[0][7:][:-5])))
```

but I think my previous version is a little more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort the dict itself by definition of what a dict is.
But you can sort its keys in any custom order by passing the desired 'key' argument into **sorted** function

> sorted(iterable[, cmp[, key[, reverse]]])

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: `cmp` is inefficient and deprecated(removed in Python 3). Did you mean `key`?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the keys of a dictionary into a list, with the additional key-Argument:

```
dict_str = {'Number_1_item':'foo',
            'Number_11_item':'bar',
            'Number_22_item':'foobar',
            'Number_5_item':'barfoo'}
sorted_keys = sorted(dict_str, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1]))
```